# group by custom date

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I want to "group by" my results by year and month using a field that has a format of 
`YYYY-MM-DD`. I want to group them by month, so with a format of `YYYY-MM` . I tried with a Terms aggregation to group them but with no avail, so now I went and looked at the `DateHistogram` aggregation and tried the following but it still doesn't work.

```
$date_grp_agg = new \Elastica\Aggregation\DateHistogram('achats_date');
$date_grp_agg->setField('achats_date')->setFormat("MM-yyy")->setInterval('1');
```

Does any of you know how to correctly group my results using a formated date field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple

```
$date_grp_agg = new \Elastica\Aggregation\DateHistogram('achats_date');
$date_grp_agg->setField('achats_date')->setFormat("MM-yy")->setInterval('1M');
```

To group them by month, you'd need to set an interval of 1 month, that way the results would be filtered for each month.

Source : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html